# Qual é a diferença entre $animate e ngAnimate?

Tags: angularjs

No Angular 1, temos um Service chamado `$animate`. Esse já vem por padrão no Angular.

Porém temos também uma biblioteca, que é adicionada opcionalmente no projeto, chamada `ngAnimate`. Esta tem como finalidade adicionar animações no `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-show` e afins.

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre ambas?

Esse `$animate` dispensa o uso do `ngAnimate`?

Referências:

- [$animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate)
- Biblioteca [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estes dois *providers* são maneiras diferentes de lidar com o mesmo módulo, `module.animation()`.

**`ngAnimate`** é uma diretiva que é injetada em diretivas (como `ngRepeat`, `ngView`, `ngIf` e outras ) que podem se beneficiar do módulo de animação para apresentar diferencas de estado.

**`$animate`** é um serviço que permite que você lide programaticamente com o módulo de animação, disparando eventos de classes (`$animate.addClass()`, `.removeClass()`, `.enter()`, `.leave()` e outros).

Comment: Excelente, mestre! :D